# Stop runnable on button click

Tags: android

I have Runnable and have two Handlers for button background color change after some music is played.
Now how can I stop the music played using runnable for a ever delay of 700 mili sec on a button click named stop.

```
     handler=new Handler(); 
    runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    for (int i = 0; i<Uirkeys1.length; i++) {
        final int value = i;
        try {

               Thread.sleep(700);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
              handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

        copyView.get(cnt1).getBackground().setAlpha(100);
        ModeSound(Integer.parseInt(CopyMultimap.get(copykey[cnt1]).get(3)));                        
                 }
                 });
                try {   
             Thread.sleep(800);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
              handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                     public void run() 
                  copyView.get(cnt1).getBackground().setAlpha(500);               
                    cnt1++;
                         }
                      });
                          }
                         }
                             };
                 new Thread(runnable).start();
                 cnt1=0;
                    }
                });
}
```

Comment: can set the boolean value and based upon the condition stop your task orelse use removecallbacks

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class MyRunnable that implements Runnable, and create a field in it

```
     private boolean stopped = false;
     public void stop() { stopped = true; }
```

And then you should check in your execution loop

```
        if(!stopped) {..do work..} else return .
```

And you can of course call the stop() method on your MyRunnable object.